# C++ - Iterate over vector of doubles as tuples

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, c++17

I have a C++ vector of doubles, which is guaranteed to have an even number of elements. This vector stores the coordinates of a set of points as x, y coordinates:

A[2 * i ] is the x coordinate of the i'th point.

A[2 * i + 1] is the y coordinate of the i'th point.

How to implement an iterator that allows me to use STL style algorithms (one that takes an iterator range, where dereferencing an iterator gives back the pair of doubles corresponding to the x, y coordinates of the corresponding point) ?

I'm using C++17 if that helps.

Comment: I assume you are looking for a "lazy" way, which gets away without copying/reformatting, right?

Comment: Correct - I assumed anyone who can answer it would understand the intent :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use range-v3, with two adapters:

- `chunk(n)` takes a range and adapts it into a range of non-overlapping ranges of size `n`
- `transform(f)` takes a range of `x` and adapts it into a range of `f(x)`

Putting those together we can create an adaptor which takes a range and yields a range of non-overlapping pairs:

```cpp
auto into_pairs = rv::chunk(2)
                | rv::transform([](auto&& r){ return std::pair(r[0], r[1]); });
```

Using the `r[0]` syntax assumes that the input range is random-access, which in this case is fine since we know we want to use it on a `vector`, but it can also be generalized to work for forward-only ranges at the cost of a bit more syntax:

```cpp
| rv::transform([](auto&& r){
      auto it = ranges::begin(r);
      auto next = ranges::next(it);
      return std::pair(*it, *next);
  })
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rKz9vb8n7), using `fmt` for convenient printing:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5};

    auto into_pairs = rv::chunk(2)
                    | rv::transform([](auto&& r){ return std::pair(r[0], r[1]); });

    // prints {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)}
    fmt::print("{}\n", v | into_pairs);
}
```

---

It's unclear from the question if you wanted `pair<T, T>`s or `pair<T&, T&>`s. The latter is doable by providing explicit types to `std::pair` rather than relying on class template argument deduction.

Comment: Wow, nice solution! Yes, references as far as possible to avoid copying is preferable - so instead of `auto &&`, i should use `pair<int&, int&>` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a bit of a moving target - also when it comes to iterators (c++20 has concepts for that...). But would it not be nice to have a lazy solution to the problem. I.e. The tuples get generated on the fly, without casting (see other answers) and without having to write a loop to transform a `vector<double>` to a `vector<tuple<double,double>>`?

Now I feel I need a disclaimer because I am not sure this is entirely correct (language lawyers will hopefully point out, if I missed something). But it compiles and produces the expected output. That is something, yes?! Yes.

The idea is to build a pseudo container (which actually is just a facade to an underlying container) with an iterator of its own, producing the desired output type on the fly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <class SourceIter>
struct PairWise {
  PairWise() = delete;
  PairWise(SourceIter first, SourceIter last) 
    : first{first}
    , last{last}
  {
  }
  using value_type = 
    typename std::tuple<
      typename SourceIter::value_type, 
      typename SourceIter::value_type
        >; 
  using source_iter = SourceIter;
  struct IterState {
    PairWise::source_iter first;
    PairWise::source_iter last;
    PairWise::source_iter current;
    IterState(PairWise::source_iter first, PairWise::source_iter last)
      : first{first}
      , last{last}
      , current{first}
    {
    }
    friend bool operator==(const IterState& a, const IterState& b) {
      // std::cout << "operator==(a,b)" << std::endl;
      return (a.first == b.first) 
        && (a.last == b.last)
        && (a.current == b.current);
    }
    IterState& operator++() {
      // std::cout << "operator++()" << std::endl;
      if (std::distance(current,last) >= 2) {
        current++;
        current++;
      }
      return *this;
    }
    const PairWise::value_type operator*() const {
      // std::cout << "operator*()" << std::endl;
      return std::make_tuple(*current, *(current+1));
    }
  };
  using iterator = IterState;
  using const_iterator = const IterState;
  const_iterator cbegin() const {
    return IterState{first,last};
  }
  const_iterator cend() const {
    auto i = IterState{first,last};
    i.current = last;    
    return i;
  }
  
  const_iterator begin() const {
    // std::cout << "begin()" << std::endl;
    return IterState{first,last};
  }
  const_iterator end() const {
    // std::cout << "end()" << std::endl;
    auto i = IterState{first,last};
    i.current = last;    
    return i;
  }
  source_iter first;
  source_iter last;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<double,double>& value) {
  auto [a,b] = value;
  os << "<" << a << "," << b << ">";
  return os;
}

template <class Container>
auto pairwise( const Container& container) 
  -> PairWise<typename Container::const_iterator> 
{
  return PairWise(container.cbegin(), container.cend());
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  using VecF64_t = std::vector<double>;

  VecF64_t data{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };
  for (const auto x : pairwise(data)) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements in vector are stored in contiguous memory area, so you can use simple pointer arithmetics to access pair of doubles.

`operator++` for iterator should skip 2 doubles at every use.

`operator*` can return tuple of references to double values, so you can read (`pair = *it`) or edit values (`*it = pair`).

```
struct Cont {
    std::vector<double>& v;
    Cont(std::vector<double>& v) : v(v) {}

    struct Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag , std::pair<double,double>> {
        double* ptrData = nullptr;

        Iterator(double* data) : ptrData(data) {}

        Iterator& operator++() { ptrData += 2; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator copy(*this); ptrData += 2; return copy; }
        auto operator*() { return std::tie(*ptrData,*(ptrData+1)); }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { return ptrData != other.ptrData; }
    };

    auto begin() { return Iterator(v.data()); }
    auto end() { return Iterator(v.data()+v.size());}
};


int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.resize(4);

    Cont c(v);
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); it++) {
        *it = std::tuple<double,double>(20,30);
    }
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl; // 20
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl; // 30
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W4f1zMv9W)

Answer (score -1):

There's not an easy "C++" way to do this that's clean and avoids a copy of the original array.  There's always this (make a copy):

```
vector<double> A; // your original list of points
vector<pair<double,double>> points;

for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size()/2; i+= 2)
{
    points[i*2] = pair<double,double>(A[i], A[i+1]);
}
```

The following would likely work, violates a few standards, and the language lawyers will sue me in court for suggesting it.  But if we can assume that the `sizeof(XY)` is the size of two doubles, has no padding, and expected alignment then cheating with a cast will likely work.  This assumes you don't need a `std::pair`

**Non standard stuff ahead**

```
vector<double> A; // your original list of points

struct XY {
   double x;
   double y;
};

static_assert(sizeof(double)*2 == sizeof(XY));

static_assert(alignof(double) == alignof(XY));

XY* points = reinterpret_cast<XY*>(A.data());
size_t numPoints = A.size()/2;

// iterate
for (size_t i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {

     XY& point = points[i];

     cout << point.x << "," << point.y << endl;
}
```

Comment: I find advertising UB like this highly questionable. Your reasoning for why it might work doesn’t help. Padding etc. isn’t the main issue. The optimizer being allowed to assume no UB is present is. Unfortunately you don’t address that at all. Bottom line: DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME.

Comment: If you add `static_asert(alignof(double) == alignof(XY));` I'd say there's no UB at all. It would be a good example of defensive programming and the only consideration is that in systems where the assumptions don't hold, the code simply breaks (but I highly doubt this is not portable).

Answer (score -2):

If you can guarantee that std::vector will always have an even number of entries, you could exploit the fact that an vector of doubles will have the same memory layout as a vector of pairs of doubles. This is kind of a dirty trick though so I wouldn't recommend it if you can avoid it. The good news is that the standard guarantees that vector elements will be contiguous.

```
inline const std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& make_dbl_pair(std::vector<double>& v)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>&>(v);
}
```

This will only work for iteration with iterators. The size is likely to be double the number of pairs in the vector because it is still a vector of doubles underneath.

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<double> dbl_vec = { 0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 };
  const std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& pair_vec = make_dbl_pair(dbl_vec);
  for (auto it = pair_vec.begin(); it != pair_vec.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "Size: " << dbl_vec.size() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```